# Including special character and subcript properly in DiagrammeR

Tags: r, diagrammer

suppose I want to include

≤

in a flowchart using DiagrammeR. However,

```
DiagrammeR::grViz("
  digraph test {
    node[shape = rectangle]
    node1 [label = <u<sub>T</sub>: &mu;<sub>T</sub> &le;>]
    node2 [label = B]

    node1 -> node2
  }
")
```

[image]

cause large gap between mu and its subscript T. The issue seems to have been raised in [github](https://github.com/rich-iannone/DiagrammeR/issues/71) years ago.

On the other hand,

```
DiagrammeR::mermaid("
      graph LR; 
      A[u<sub>T</sub>: &mu;<sub>T</sub> ]--> B")
DiagrammeR::mermaid("
      graph LR; 
      A[u<sub>T</sub>: &mu;<sub>T</sub> &le;]--> B")
```

cause special character ≤ `%le;` to break the plot.
[image]
[image]

Is there an alternative solution? Thank you.